# How to make an answer bold in html?

Tags: html

I have no clue about programming. I am filling out a resume on a web site and they want me to make my answer bold. I believe it is in html format. Inspect displays

```
<input type="TEXT" name="fn" value size="20" maxlength="40"
id="fn" onblur="this.value=spaceTrim(this.value);
validName(this,false,null,null,null,true,false);">
```

How would I make the answer bold?

Comment: Do you fill the answer in an `Html Editor`?

Comment: You can use CSS styling. In short add attribute style="font-weight:bold;" . or is there something I didn't understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
<strong> tags </strong>
```

You can use " **strong tags** "

to make text bold

Comment: You can use surround some text in backticks to make it display literally like `<strong>strong tags</strong>`

Comment: Yeah I couldn't get the <strong> tags to show and not just make my answer bold

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `style` attribute of the `input` tag:

```
style="font-weight:bold"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-weight: bold` for your `style`.

```html
<input type="TEXT" name="fn" value size="20" maxlength="40"
id="fn" onblur="this.value=spaceTrim(this.value);
validName(this,false,null,null,null,true,false);" style="font-weight: bold">
```

Comment: welcome, so please select it as the correct answer. @DaveT